# MS Access SQL Deleting from grouped field by max value when there is more than one

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am using SQL queries on a MS Access database and have a table like the following:

```
Team           Country  City     Firstname  Surname     RecordedDateTime
Group Panda 7  USA      New York Jim        Smith       12/07/2016 09:10:06
Group Tiger 5  USA      Boston   Jack       Thompson    05/07/2016 19:15:21
Group Goat 12  USA      New York Jim        Smith       12/07/2016 09:10:06
Group Lion 9   France   Paris    Tom        Pryor       06/07/2016 10:10:08
Group Eagle 2  USA      New York Dale       Wycliff     12/07/2016 12:28:09
.....
```

Now, I'm trying to delete the records with: the latest date/time (so would be more than one maximum); have the same Country, City, Firstname and Surname; those that don't have "Panda" in the Team, or if there's no "Panda" then those that don't have "Goat" in the Team, or if there's no "Goat" then those that don't have "Lion" in the Team and so on. So for Jim Smith, I want to delete the third record displayed.

Hopefully, that makes sense. So far, I can delete records older than the latest date/time with the following:

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW T1.* FROM Results T1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT Country, City, Firstname, Surname, MAX(RecordedDateTime) AS LatestTime
FROM Results GROUP BY Country, City, Firstname, Surname) T2 ON T1.Country = T2.Country AND T1.City = T2.City
AND T1.Firstname = T2.Firstname AND T1.Surname = T2.Surname WHERE T1.RecordedDateTime <> T2.LatestTime
```

But the problem is handling more than one maximum and the conditions for part of a field.

Comment: Start from here: [Why is my query read-only](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html)? You can't delete from a read only query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `WHERE` clause subqueries for the delete query to be [*updateable*](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html) and hence *deleteable*. Your needs are a bit unusual as you require a specific team order that is neither numeric or string ordered. Therefore, a nested `IIF()` is used to give such an ordering with `Pandas (lowest) < Tiger < Goat < Lion < Eagle (highest)`.

```
DELETE *
FROM Results T1 
WHERE (T1.RecordDateTime <>

    (SELECT MAX(RecordDateTime) AS LatestTime
     FROM Results sub
     WHERE sub.Country = T1.Country 
     AND sub.City = T1.City
     AND sub.Firstname = T1.Firstname 
     AND sub.Surname = T1.Surname 
     GROUP BY Country, City, Firstname, Surname))

OR (NOT IIF(Team LIKE '*Panda*', 1, 
            IIF(Team LIKE '*Tiger*', 2, 
                IIF(Team LIKE '*Goat*', 3,
                    IIF(Team LIKE '*Lion*', 4, 
                        IIF(Team LIKE '*Eagle*', 5, NULL))))) IN

    (SELECT MIN(IIF(Team LIKE '*Panda*', 1, 
                    IIF(Team LIKE '*Goat*', 2, 
                        IIF(Team LIKE '*Goat*', 3, 
                            IIF(Team LIKE '*Lion*', 4, 
                                IIF(Team LIKE '*Eagle*', 5, NULL))))))
     FROM Results sub
     WHERE sub.Country = T1.Country 
     AND sub.City = T1.City
     AND sub.Firstname = T1.Firstname 
     AND sub.Surname = T1.Surname 
     GROUP BY Country, City, Firstname, Surname))
```

Should there be more team orderings, add to the conditional logic or better yet use a lookup table to be joined with *Results* table. This way you avoid the nested `IIF()` and simply use *TeamValue*:

```
Team              TeamValue
Group Panda 7             1
Group Tiger 5             2
Group Goat 12             3
Group Lion 9              4
Group Eagle 2             5
...
```

Comment: Thank you - that's some pretty neat code. It also makes sense in the WHERE part as well. Ok, so you're deleting the records if they aren't equal to the max time and then checking the team. This I'm not quite getting. It's checking for example if "(2) IN (2)", which is always true and the not changes it to false? Sorry, could you please highlight the logic in this part? Have tested and it does work results wise though :)

Comment: ok, after rereading it again, I think I have it. It's compared to the lowest team number in the current group of results equal in all fields apart from Team. If it's not, then evaluates to the true for deletion. Is that right? Thanks again btw, this has stretched my mind :)

Comment: Correct. `WHERE` conditions check if time is not equal to max **or** if current group is not lowest team number.